# Where can I find an electric generator that produces electricity when spun?

Tags: generator

I am fairly new to electrical engineering (I am much more skilled on software rather than hardware), and I am starting to pick up on building circuits and such.

I am attempting to design several of my own methods of power generation, however I do not want to build my own generator (the physical device). 
For example: I want to build a set of bicycles that can be hooked up to a generator via a belt, but I want the generator that uses my spin from the bikes to generate the electricity.

Every time I search up generators for sale, it comes up with the portable gas generators. What retailers may sell what I want, or what better way do I have for searching for the generator?

Comment: At your local motor store.

Comment: VTC (vote to close) because this is a shopping type question as opposed to a electronics design question.

Comment: Try looking for an "alternator" or a "dc generator" instead.

Comment: This is a shopping question. Vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to electrical circuits, I would suggest using small DC motor as generator to get the "feel" of how circuits work before buying an actual generator and getting into serious stuff.

A DC motor can generate electricity when it's shaft is spun(although it is not designed to do this efficiently, it will work just fine for simple applications). Get a 3v or 6v DC motor from an electronics hobby shop. Fix it to the frame of the bike such that the shaft of the motor touches the metal rim of the tire(You will have to find a suitable rubber bearing to make firm contact). Connect a 3v LED and a 470 ohm resistor in series across the motor terminals. Spin the wheel of the bike. The LED should light up. Enjoy!